# transformation of variable for pdf

Tags: probability

Probability density function is uniform on the interval (0,1)

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}  1,\quad  & 0< x< 1 \\  0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

How do i use the transformation of variables method to find:

$$X^{1/2}$$ $$-X^2$$

Comment: This can help: http://www.stat.washington.edu/~nehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT395_functions-random-variables.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The Change of Variables theorem, is essentially the Chain Rule of Differentiation, with care taken for possible folding of intervals (when $X(\Omega)\mapsto Y(\Omega)$ is not a bijection).

---

$Y=X^{1/2}$ and $X\sim\mathcal U [0;1]$ means we use: $f_Y(y)=\tfrac1 2\lvert\frac{\mathrm d y^2}{\mathrm d y}\rvert\cdot\mathbf 1_{y^2\in[0;1]}$

The factor of $\tfrac 12$ being due to the support of $X$ being unfolded onto the support of $Y$.

---

$Y=-X^2$ and $X\sim\mathcal U [0;1]$ means we use: $f_Y(y)=\lvert\frac{\mathrm d \sqrt{-y}}{\mathrm d y}\rvert\cdot\mathbf 1_{\sqrt{-y}\in[0;1]}$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "Transformation of Variables", but in these simple cases you can just write down what you are wanting to get and manipulate to what you know. Here, I assume you are looking for the cdf and/or pdf of these random variables. For example, the cdf of $X^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is given by:

$$P(X^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq x) = P(X \leq x^2) = \int_{0}^{x^2} 1 \ dt = x^2 $$

for $x \in [0,1]$.

Therefore the pdf is $2x$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

The other works similarly.